# How to execute a function after one function containing Set time out is completed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asynchronous, callback

So I am working on a project: Linked List Visualizer and I am having some problem on calling a function after one is completed. More specifically the first function call is of an animation using Set time out that animates the node borders and arrows to show the traversing of the list. Then after the animation is done I want to add the node to the list. The problem is that the way I am doing it, both functions are called simultaneously so while animation is playing the node is added as well which is not what I want. I want the the animation to end first then add the node to the linked list. This is what I have so far:

```js
let mainContainer = document.querySelector(".container");

let items = mainContainer.children;



function nodeColorChange(item, delay){
    setTimeout(() => {
        item.classList.add('changeNodeColor')
      }, delay)
      

}

function arrowColorChange(item, delay){
    setTimeout(() => {
        item.classList.add('changeArrowColor')
      }, delay)

}




let buttonClick = document.getElementById("submitButton");
let userInfo = document.getElementById("userInput");

function addNode(userInput){
    let newArrow = document.createElement("div");
    newArrow.classList.add("arrow");
    mainContainer.appendChild(newArrow);

    let newNode = document.createElement("div");
    let nodeValue = document.createElement("p");
    nodeValue.innerHTML = userInput;
    newNode.appendChild(nodeValue);
    newNode.classList.add("node");

    mainContainer.appendChild(newNode);

}


 async function main(){

    for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    
        if(items[i].classList.contains("node")){
            nodeColorChange(items[i], i * 1000);
            /// we will need to remove the class so that this animation
            /// is played again every time the user add a node
            items[i].classList.remove("changeNodeColor");
        }else{
            arrowColorChange(items[i], i * 1000);
            items[i].classList.remove("changeArrowColor");
        }
    }


    


    
    
}


buttonClick.addEventListener("click", function(){
    
    main().then(
        function(value){addNode(userInfo.value)},
        function(error){console.log("Animation not done")}
    );

});
```

```css
.inputField{
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


.node{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    


}

.arrow{
    background-color: black;
    height: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    
}

.changeNodeColor{
    animation: nodeColorChange 0.9s;

}

@keyframes nodeColorChange{
    0%{border-color: black;}
    100%{border-color: red;}
}

.changeArrowColor{
    animation: arrowColorChange 0.9s;
}

@keyframes arrowColorChange{
    0%{background-color: black;}
    100%{background-color: red;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/PracticeAnimation/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="node">
        <p>30</p>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow">

    </div>
    <div class="node">
        <p>40</p>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow">

    </div>
    <div class="node">
        <p>50</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="inputField">
    <input id="userInput" type="text">
    <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>

</div>

<script src="/PracticeAnimation/app.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

So I have tried using an async function so that I could first execute the main function which consist of the animation, then after that is done I could execute the addNode function which adds the node. The problem is that the animation is playing while adding the node, and I want the animation to finish first then add the node. How can I can execute the addNode function after the main() function is completed?

Comment: execute the second function inside the function that setTimeout calls - `async` works in conjunction with `await`, `await` waits for Promises (exclusively) to resolve - setTimeout has nothing to do with Promises

Comment: you could create a helper function `const setTimeoutPromise = (cb, ms, ...args) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => r(cb(...args), ms)));` ... use that instead of `setTimeout` ... make sure you return that where you use it, and then you can use `await` in your `async` function